# Need a data.table method to use a lagged computed value by group

Tags: r, data.table

Sample data:

```
> DT <- data.table(yr=rep(1:4,2), grp=sort(rep(c('a','b'),4)), val=c(25,20,NA,NA,10,12,NA,NA))
> DT
   yr grp val
1:  1   a  25
2:  2   a  20
3:  3   a  NA
4:  4   a  NA
5:  1   b  10
6:  2   b  12
7:  3   b  NA
8:  4   b  NA
```

I want to compute `val2` as half of `val`.  For `yr<=2` the equation is `val2==0.5*val`.  However, starting in `yr==3`, `val2` is half of the previous year `yr` computed `val2` for a given group `grp`.  So ideally I would get:

```
   yr grp val val2
1:  1   a  25 12.5
2:  2   a  20 10.0
3:  3   a  NA  5.0
4:  4   a  NA  2.5
5:  1   b  10  5.0
6:  2   b  12  6.0
7:  3   b  NA  3.0
8:  4   b  NA  1.5
```

I prefer to avoid a loop since my really data is very large.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 DT[, val2 := nafill(val, "locf")/2^(1 + cumsum(is.na(val))), grp]
 DT
   yr grp val val2
1:  1   a  25 12.5
2:  2   a  20 10.0
3:  3   a  NA  5.0
4:  4   a  NA  2.5
5:  1   b  10  5.0
6:  2   b  12  6.0
7:  3   b  NA  3.0
8:  4   b  NA  1.5
```

Comment: This is perfect.  One question, the by grouping is technically yr and grp (not just grp).  Does this work because the data are sorted already?  What modification would be needed (if any) in an unsorted data table (both yr and grp)?

Comment: @jsirgo `yr` and `grp` are antagonistic of each other. You cannot group by both. If you do, then you will have each row as a group. Your data need not be sorted. The code will still work

Comment: Excellent.  What if the value of ```val2``` wasn't always ```0.5 * val``` but instead ```x * val``` where ```x``` is another column with a variety of values?

Answer (score 2):

here is an option

```
library(data.table)
DT[, val2 := val/2, grp]
DT[, val2 := replace(val2, is.na(val2),
   last(na.omit(val2))/2^(seq_len(sum(is.na(val2))))), grp]
```

-output

```
DT
#   yr grp val val2
#1:  1   a  25 12.5
#2:  2   a  20 10.0
#3:  3   a  NA  5.0
#4:  4   a  NA  2.5
#5:  1   b  10  5.0
#6:  2   b  12  6.0
#7:  3   b  NA  3.0
#8:  4   b  NA  1.5
```